# Averaging ADC readings have strange steps in plot

Tags: c++, microcontroller, atmega, adc

Im reading ADC values for measuring temperatures and i average them. But the plot from it shows "steps", but not from actual steps of the values increasing. Does anyone know why this happens?

```
#include "arduino.h"

#define AVG_COUNT 1300
#define AVG_MAX_COUNT (2147483647/1023)
#define AVG_DURATION_TIME (AVG_COUNT * 150)

#define LOOP_INTERVAL 250

#define LOOP_INTERVAL_X 100

#define E 2.7182818284
#define AREF 4945.0

#define VREF 4945.0 // 3004 at about 22°C and 3012 at about 0°C
//#define S1_R_REF 15000.0
#define S1_R_REF_DIV4 3750.0
#define S1_RM 6260

#define S1_A_1 0.003354016
#define S1_B_1 0.0002744030
#define S1_C_1 0.00000366694
#define S1_D_1 0.000000137549

byte last_ADMUX = 0;
#define ADC_BANDGAP ((1 << MUX3) | (1 << MUX2) |  (1 << MUX1))
#define ADC_RAW_BANDGAP 1110

#define T_B 5.255
#define T_A_x100 0.65

int temperature;

#define SUM_COUNT 10

int getADCRaw(){
    //Start conversion
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);

    //wait for Measurment to finish
    while(ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC));

    return (ADCL | (ADCH << 8));
}

int getTempX100(int RntcDiv4){
    return (int) (100 / (S1_A_1 + S1_B_1*log(RntcDiv4/S1_R_REF_DIV4) + S1_C_1*pow(log(RntcDiv4/S1_R_REF_DIV4),2) + S1_D_1*pow(log(RntcDiv4/S1_R_REF_DIV4), 3) ));
}


int getTempAvg(int avgCount){
    unsigned long rmSum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < avgCount; i++){
        rmSum += (unsigned long) getADCRaw();;
    }

    float rmAvg = mapFloat((float)rmSum / avgCount, 0, 1023, 0, AREF);

    int rntcDiv4 = (int) ((VREF / rmAvg - 1) * S1_RM / 4);

    int tempCelsiusX100 = getTempX100(rntcDiv4) - 27315;

    delay(1);
    return tempCelsiusX100;
}

unsigned long getXBase10(byte exponent){
    unsigned long rValue = 1;

    for(;exponent > 0; exponent--){
        rValue *= 10;
    }
    return rValue;
}

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(57600);
    //Pin A0input
    DDRC &= ~(1 << PC0);

    ADMUX |= (1 << REFS0);  // 5V AREF (ADC0 is 0 by default)
}


unsigned long printTime = 0;
unsigned long nowMillis = 0;
unsigned long measTime = 0;

unsigned long lastPrintTime = 0;

#define INTERVAL 250

void loop(){
  nowMillis = millis();
  int temp = getTempAvg(20);

  measTime = millis() - nowMillis;

  while(millis() - lastPrintTime < INTERVAL)
    delayMicroseconds(333);

  Serial.println(measTime);

  Serial.flush();
  lastPrintTime = millis();
}
```

With the averaging i wanted to increase the resolution so i would not have those big steps. And more precise readings. Why in the world are those steps there?

[image: big steps and small steps]

Answer (score 4):

I didn't verify all the integer math to make sure you don't have a rounding problem, but assuming you don't, and 0.1 degrees corresponds to the resolution of your ADC, then...

The problem is that you don't have enough noise in the input circuit.

If you don't have enough noise, then the ADC will provide the value closest to the real temperature.  This doesn't change, so if you average a bunch together then you pretty much get the same value.

On the other hand, if you have a few LSB worth of noise in the analog signal you're sampling, then the ADC will produce values according to a probability distribution, and the center of that distribution -- the average value -- will change to reflect even small changes in the real temperature.

The proper term for this is "dithering".  It's more commonly understood in image quantization, but it's used for quantizing 1D signals as well:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither

Adding input noise will, of course, make your output more noisy and less precise initially, but it looks like you have lots of room to increase the length of the averaging process to make up for that.

The easiest way to get the noise into your circuit is probably to generate it yourself.  There's a good article on how to do that with arduino here: https://thecavepearlproject.org/2017/02/27/enhancing-arduinos-adc-resolution-by-dithering-oversampling/

Comment: Wow i newer thought that noise could be useful. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The issues looks to be that your average is an average over a very short time period.  Assuming the A2D takes 1us to complete, you are taking data over a 20us window.  From there, the routine does a simple average (rmSum / avgCount) and a lookup.  From there, you do some perhaps overly complicated calculation to generate a single result.  This final value (tempCelsiusX100 & temp) is never used as part of an average in the next cycle.  Temperatures change relatively slowly; it's ok to take 20 readings in a row, but again, this is effectively the same reading.  You need to create a weighted rolling average that uses previous values and delivers an average over a much longer period of time.
For example, in the loop portion, you get a new value every ~250ms, you should average 10 of those values given an overall average over 2.5 seconds.  I would recommend a weighted rolling average where the most recent value gets weighted higher than the previous.  Using a rolling buffer of 10 values limits the influence from readings too far in the past.